# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed - invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, elasticsearch

I am trying to post from a form that is being created in a MVC view but I am receiving a 405.0 error.  I have added this controller and view into an existing project attempting to implement ElasticSearchCRUD.  I have other controllers that are functioning properly in the project.   Isn't the HttpPost attribute on the Index method in the controller all that is needed?

Here is the relevant code:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search"))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset class="form">
    <legend>CREATE a new document in the search engine</legend>
    <table width="500">
        <tr>
           ....
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Add" style="width:200px" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<form action="/Search" method="post">    <fieldset class="form">
    <legend>CREATE a new document in the search engine</legend>
    <table width="500">
        <tr>
         ....
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Material" style="width:200px" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
            model.Updated = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _searchProvider.AddUpdateEntity(model);

            return Redirect("Search/Index");
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Comment: did you tried debugging with chrome or firefox web console to be sure about the action form? because seems that your form post to /Search

Comment: Your code works fine i.e. It works as expected, there must be something other than the code shown above which is playing a role. Try this code on a new MVC project and go from there.

Comment: So the code above works fine in a new mvc project.  I have installed WebAPI in this project.  Could this be causing problems with routing?   All MVC controllers derive from a BaseController class of type Controller.